# How do I fix bluetooth audio not working for only some apps

Tags: bluetooth, audio, headphones, troubleshooting

I have a pair of Sony bluetooth headphones and they work perfectly with my phone (Moto G30) for Spotify and YouTube, however audio does not play through them for some other apps (BaconReader and Polytopia to name two).

When I have one of these apps open and I turn the volume up, the audio pop up shows the master value turning up but the app in question's audio slider is still stuck at the bottom. If I manually try to slide it up it just jumps back to the bottom.

This doesn't happen with my wired earphones and I do not have another Bluetooth headset to test on.

I have "forgotten" the headphones and repaired them to no avail. Restarting my phone doesn't help. Killing the apps and starting them again doesn't help.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Double-check the app permissions...

Comment: Try switching to SBC codec

Comment: @keshlam nothing wrong with app permissions I'm afraid.

Comment: @karthiknair I gotta be honest I don't know what that is.

Comment: @TeddyTedTed go to Bluetooth settings on your phone. Locate your headset that is connected and you must see a settings clog icon for that headset, tap on it. Within the options enlisted in that menu you just tapped, you must see a toggle called AAC/aptx/HD audio. Turn that off